# Creating pages with Nesta on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, content-management-system, sinatra, nestacms

I am looking to roll a simple CMS with Ruby and preferably Sinatra. www.nestacms.com looks like a terrific candidate.

Some key objectives:

- Allow business users to add/edit/remove pages (not via `git` but via app functionality)
- Deploy on Heroku

As I understand, Nesta pages are generated by static page files in your deployment. Which is fine if you add via `git` and push to Heroku.

But if you're wanting to create pages (files) in a Heroku web app, this isn't possible due to Heroku's read-only file system.

Looking for help around:

- Achieving objectives with Nesta and Heroku
- Alternative approaches

Comment: Having looked at (but not used) Nesta, would it be easy to have it store articles in a database instead of generating files?

Comment: Thanks @phoffer Yes, that's an alternative approach to consider

Comment: Did you see [locomotive cms](http://locomotivecms.com/)? I can't comment if it would be straight forward to modify Nesta to back it with DB.

Comment: Thanks @Ck Yes, but strongly preferring Sinatra if possible ;) Ideal would be Nesta + DB. Looking at rolling a simple one, at this stage

Comment: @Ck Have been checking out http://locomotivecms.com If I have to use Rails, it looks like a great candidate. What do you like about it? What annoys you? :)

Comment: @DanielMay I am just aware of it, never had the chance to work with either of them.

Answer (score 0):

[Github](https://github.com) has an [editor](https://help.github.com/categories/81/articles) to manipulate files and buttons to create/merge branches in browser.

You may want store your content related media on a cloud storage services (such as [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), [google drive](https://drive.google.com), [cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com) etc.) You also can connect/mount these storages like drives via WebDAV or some other tools depending on your prefered service provider & OS.

[snap-ci](https://snap-ci.com) offers free and easy to use integration service for automated tests and/or deployment ([heroku](https://heroku.com) or your VPS/server). When master branch changed [github](https://github.com) webhook triggers [snap-ci](https://snap-ci.com) and your website will deploy in average 1 minute.